# How to wrap an integer to cocos2d::Object in cocos2d-x 3.0 beta?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

In cocos2d-x 2.x, there exists a class called Integer, we can use Integer::create(n) to create an Integer instance which is kind of object. However, Integer class has been deprecated since cococ2d-x 3.0 beta, is there any new way to wrap it ?

Comment: there is `__Integer` class, same as `CCInteger` for 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I finally use type intptr_t, it is a integer type that has the same size as pointer

convert from intptr_t to cocos2d::Object pointer:

```
auto obj = reinterpret_cast<cocos2d::Object *>(n);
```

and the back-wise:

```
auto n = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(obj);
```